# BERT model does not seem working properly

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, google-colaboratory, bert-language-model

I am quite new in BERT. I want to carry out a sentiment analysis based on hotel comments. I have an excel file including comments in a column and corresponding label (0 or 1) in another column. My problem is that some bars stay 0% during the execution phase as you can see on the image and I do not figure that out. Thanks for your help.

My codes:

```py
   import pandas as pd
from simpletransformers.classification import ClassificationModel

df=pd.read_excel("oteller.xlsx")

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

model = ClassificationModel('bert', 'bert-base-multilingual-uncased', num_labels=2,use_cuda=False, 
                            args={'reprocess_input_data': True, "fp16":False,'overwrite_output_dir': True, 'num_train_epochs': 3})

model.train_model(train)

result, model_outputs, wrong_predictions = model.eval_model(test)
```

[unloaded bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r3xf.png)